# solr - upload xml which have different tags than standard tags given by solr

Tags: java, xml, solr, lucene

I am new to Apache Solr, so forgive me if I am wrong. 
I have xml files which contains data as follow:

```
<page>
<title>AccessibleComputing</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>10</id>
    <redirect title="Computer accessibility" />
    <revision>
    <id>381202555</id>
    <parentid>381200179</parentid>
    <timestamp>2010-08-26T22:38:36Z</timestamp>
    <contributor>
         <username>OlEnglish</username>
         <id>7181920</id>
    </contributor>
</revision>
</page>
```

Is there any way to import these kind of files to solr and do perform search on it?
Also can we upload different types of schema to solr application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard tags are the format for Solr data upload.
It has standard commands for Add/Delete records with field names boosts and values.

If you want to index data you need to convert your data into the standard format to be able to index it.

You can also check [Solr DIH XPathEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#XPathEntityProcessor) which will allow you to index xml files and retrive values from it and set it to solr fields.

Comment: Thanks Jayendra, As per my findings, we can transform own xml file to solr either by SolrJ or by XSLT. Which is the better way to perform transorm? Its great help if you have any example to upload XML to XSLT. I found other way around like transform Solr result to XML using XSLT but there is not useful help for XML to XSLT transform.

Comment: You can have custom handling of parsing the xml file and using Solrj to feed the data into Solr OR using the DIH XPath example rss-data-config.xml example available with the download.